# What's the default hash value of an object on 64 bit JVM

Tags: java, hash

Since default hash value of an object is the object address of the object, on 32-bit machine, it makes sense considering hash value is an int value. My question is that on 64 bit machine, address is supposed to be 64 bit right? Then what about the 32 bit int hash value? Is there going to be some down conversion(from 64bit to 32 bit)?

Comment: The default hash value of an object *was* the address, in about 1997. It has never been specified to be so. It *has* been specified as 32 bits.

Comment: Technically, the Object.hashCode() is only 31-bits, i.e. it is never negative.  It has nothing to do with the address even though it might look like one when printed and the Javadoc mentions an "internal address"  You can quickly tell it is not an address by printing the object.hashCode of many objects in a row.  You would expect to see a pattern, but you do not.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: is there any specification which guarantees that `Object.hashCode()` is never negative? That would be a surprising restriction as hash codes other than the identity hash code can (and will) be negative and therefore hash maps have to be prepared for that anyway…

Comment: @Holger it's an implementation detail of Oracle/OpenJDK JVM.  The extra bit is used for another purpose around lock biasing.  This might not be true of other JVMs and I doubt it in the spec.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is that what's the default hash value for an object on 64 bit JVM? Is it still the object address value?

The "default" value ... or more specifically how an object's "identity hashcode" is calculated is NOT SPECIFIED.  Not on a 32bit JVM, or a 64bit JVM.

It is observed that the value is typically *based on* the object's address at the point that the `System.identityHashcode()` method is *first* called, but that is only an observation.  It is certainly *not* specified to be that, which means that different JVMs are free to implement it differently.

Certainly, it cannot be the actual address on a 64bit JVM ... since a 64 bit address won't fit into a 32 bit integer.  Obviously.

---

However it is actually calculated, it remains the fact that the identity hashcode is **NEVER** a reliable proxy for the object's address.  If an object with an identity hashcode survives a garbage collection cycle, the GC will *probably* have moved it, and its hashcode and address will henceforth be unrelated.  (One thing that is guaranteed is that an object's identity hashcode does not change.  If it did, hash tables would break.)

Answer (score 21):

How to calculate identity hashCode is JVM specific.

As to HotSpot JVM, it uses **random number generator** for initial calculation of identity hashCode. After the hashCode is calculated for the first time, it is saved in the object header so that subsequent calls to `identityHashCode` will return the same value.

Actually the algorithm of generating identity hashCode can be altered by `-XX:hashCode` JVM option. Look at [the sources](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/hotspot/file/d638e49facb6/src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp#l542). There are the following options:

- `-XX:hashCode=0` - global Park-Miller RNG *(default until Java 7)*
- `-XX:hashCode=1` - function(obj_address, global_state)
- `-XX:hashCode=2` - constant 1. All objects will have the same hashCode. Just for testing.
- `-XX:hashCode=3` - incremental counter.
- `-XX:hashCode=4` - lower 32 bits of the object address in the Heap
- `-XX:hashCode=5` - thread-local Marsaglia's Xor-shift RNG *(default since Java 8)*

Answer (score 3):

In the OpenJDK/HotSpot JVM you can obtain the raw index address of a reference.  This translates to a 32-bit address for a small heap and a 64-bit address for a large heap.  For medium sized heaps, 32-bit [Compressed OOPS](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops) are used.

The implementation is available in [synchronizer.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/42ca4002efc2/src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp#l246)  AFAIK, the last implementation is the one actually used.

```
/**
 * Prints the addresses and hashCode()s of the first objects in eden space.
 * <p>
 * Assumes a 32-bit address space e.g. CompressOops
 * </p>
 */
public static void main(String... ignored) throws Exception {
    Object[] objects = new Object[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        System.gc();
        for (int j = 0; j < objects.length; j++) {
            objects[j] = new Object();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < objects.length; j++) {
            long address = OBJECT_SCALE == 4 ? UNSAFE.getInt(objects, OBJECT_BASE + j * OBJECT_SCALE) & 0xFFFFFFFFL : UNSAFE.getLong(objects, OBJECT_BASE + j * OBJECT_SCALE);
            System.out.printf("%,d: addr: %8x, hc: %8x ", j, address, objects[j].hashCode());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

static final Unsafe UNSAFE;

static final int OBJECT_BASE, OBJECT_SCALE;

static {
    try {
        Field theUnsafe = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
        UNSAFE = (Unsafe) theUnsafe.get(null);
        OBJECT_BASE = UNSAFE.arrayBaseOffset(Object[].class);
        OBJECT_SCALE = UNSAFE.arrayIndexScale(Object[].class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

prints

```
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 6d6f6e28 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 29453f44 2: addr: fc000002, hc: 5cad8086 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 6e0be858 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 61bbe9ba 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 610455d6 6: addr: fc000006, hc: 511d50c0 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 60e53b93 
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 5e2de80c 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 1d44bcfa 2: addr: fc000002, hc: 266474c2 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 6f94fa3e 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 5e481248 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 66d3c617 6: addr: fc000006, hc: 63947c6b 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 2b193f2d 
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 355da254 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 4dc63996 2: addr: fc000002, hc:  d716361 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 6ff3c5b5 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 3764951d 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 4b1210ee 6: addr: fc000006, hc: 4d7e1886 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 3cd1a2f1 
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 2f0e140b 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 7440e464 2: addr: fc000002, hc: 49476842 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 78308db1 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 27c170f0 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 5451c3a8 6: addr: fc000006, hc: 2626b418 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 5a07e868 
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 76ed5528 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 2c7b84de 2: addr: fc000002, hc: 3fee733d 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 5acf9800 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 4617c264 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 36baf30c 6: addr: fc000006, hc: 7a81197d 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 5ca881b5 
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 24d46ca6 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 4517d9a3 2: addr: fc000002, hc: 372f7a8d 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 2f92e0f4 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 28a418fc 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 5305068a 6: addr: fc000006, hc: 1f32e575 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 279f2327 
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 2ff4acd0 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 54bedef2 2: addr: fc000002, hc: 5caf905d 3: addr: fc000003, hc:  27716f4 4: addr: fc000004, hc:  8efb846 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 2a84aee7 6: addr: fc000006, hc:  a09ee92 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 30f39991 
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 452b3a41 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 4a574795 2: addr: fc000002, hc:  f6f4d33 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 23fc625e 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 3f99bd52 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 4f023edb 6: addr: fc000006, hc: 3a71f4dd 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 7adf9f5f 
0: addr: fc000000, hc:  85ede7b 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 5674cd4d 2: addr: fc000002, hc: 63961c42 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 65b54208 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 1be6f5c3 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 6b884d57 6: addr: fc000006, hc: 38af3868 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 77459877 
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 5b2133b1 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 72ea2f77 2: addr: fc000002, hc: 33c7353a 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 681a9515 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 3af49f1c 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 19469ea2 6: addr: fc000006, hc: 13221655 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 2f2c9b19 
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 31befd9f 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 1c20c684 2: addr: fc000002, hc: 1fb3ebeb 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 548c4f57 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 1218025c 5: addr: fc000005, hc:  816f27d 6: addr: fc000006, hc:  87aac27 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 3e3abc88 
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 6ce253f1 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 53d8d10a 2: addr: fc000002, hc:  e9e54c2 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 65ab7765 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 1b28cdfa 5: addr: fc000005, hc:  eed1f14 6: addr: fc000006, hc: 7229724f 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 4c873330 
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 119d7047 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 776ec8df 2: addr: fc000002, hc: 4eec7777 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 3b07d329 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 41629346 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 404b9385 6: addr: fc000006, hc: 6d311334 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 682a0b20 
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 3d075dc0 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 214c265e 2: addr: fc000002, hc: 448139f0 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 7cca494b 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 7ba4f24f 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 3b9a45b3 6: addr: fc000006, hc: 7699a589 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 58372a00 
0: addr: fc000000, hc:  4dd8dc3 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 6d03e736 2: addr: fc000002, hc: 568db2f2 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 378bf509 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 5fd0d5ae 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 2d98a335 6: addr: fc000006, hc: 16b98e56 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 7ef20235 
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 27d6c5e0 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 4f3f5b24 2: addr: fc000002, hc: 15aeb7ab 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 7b23ec81 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 6acbcfc0 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 5f184fc6 6: addr: fc000006, hc: 3feba861 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 5b480cf9 
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 6f496d9f 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 723279cf 2: addr: fc000002, hc: 10f87f48 3: addr: fc000003, hc:  b4c966a 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 2f4d3709 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 4e50df2e 6: addr: fc000006, hc: 1d81eb93 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 7291c18f 
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 34a245ab 1: addr: fc000001, hc: 7cc355be 2: addr: fc000002, hc: 6e8cf4c6 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 12edcd21 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 34c45dca 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 52cc8049 6: addr: fc000006, hc: 5b6f7412 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 27973e9b 
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 312b1dae 1: addr: fc000001, hc:  7530d0a 2: addr: fc000002, hc: 27bc2616 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 3941a79c 4: addr: fc000004, hc: 506e1b77 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 4fca772d 6: addr: fc000006, hc:  9807454 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 3d494fbf 
0: addr: fc000000, hc: 1ddc4ec2 1: addr: fc000001, hc:  133314b 2: addr: fc000002, hc:  b1bc7ed 3: addr: fc000003, hc: 7cd84586 4: addr: fc000004, hc:  30dae81 5: addr: fc000005, hc: 1b2c6ec2 6: addr: fc000006, hc: 4edde6e5 7: addr: fc000007, hc: 70177ecd
```

For CompressedOops and heaps between 3-30 GB, it gives you an idea of the memory location (but it is translated)  In the case above, the addresses are `index * 8`  The `8` comes from the allocation block size which is 8 bytes by default.  It can be increased to 16 or 32 in Java 8, although using 16 is only useful for heaps of 32 - 64 GB, and 32 might not be useful at all as a 32 byte allocation size might be more expensive than using 64-bit references

As you can see, each object was allocated in the same space after a System.gc().  The addresses are the same each time, however the hashCode

- has little to do with the address
- is only 31-bit, there is nothing starting `8` to `F` in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

In Java an `int` is 32-bits. Even on a 64-bit native machine. See `Integer.SIZE`. Also, Oracle's [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) Tutorial says (in part) -

> **int:** By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -2<sup>31</sup> and a maximum value of 2<sup>31</sup>-1. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the int data type to represent an unsigned 32-bit integer, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 2<sup>32</sup>-1. Use the Integer class to use int data type as an unsigned integer. See the section The Number Classes for more information. Static methods like compareUnsigned, divideUnsigned etc have been added to the Integer class to support the arithmetic operations for unsigned integers.

The [`Object#hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) Javadoc says,

> (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the Java<sup>TM</sup> programming language.)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My question is that what's the default hash value for an object on 64 bit JVM? Is it still the object address value?

Comment: @BillRanderson An algorithm that produces a 32-bit `int` as per the [`Object#hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) Javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know and test, the most reliable way to get native address from JVM internal addess in case of compressed-oops mode, is using **"getNarrowOopBase"** and **"getNarrowOopShift"**  methods of **"sun.jvm.hotspot.memory.Universe"** class and that class can be available in case of using **"Java HotSpot Serviceability Agent"**.

Native address can be calculated as:

```
if (compressedRef) {
    return (address >> compressRefShift) - compressRefBase;
} 
else {
    return address;
}
```

Here are usages of it

https://github.com/serkan-ozal/jillegal/blob/master/src/main/java/tr/com/serkanozal/jillegal/util/HotspotJvmInfoUtil.java

https://github.com/serkan-ozal/jillegal/blob/master/src/main/java/tr/com/serkanozal/jillegal/util/JvmUtil.java