# Hashcode doesn't change between reruns

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

```
object Main extends App {
  var a = new AnyRef()
  println(a hashCode)
}
```

I have this code in Intellij Idea. I noticed that hashcode does not change between reruns. Even more, it doesn't change if I restart idea, or do some light modifications to the code. I can rename variable `a` or add a few more variables and I still have the same hashcode.

Is it cached somewhere? Or it's just OS who allocated the same address to a variable? Any consequences of this?

I'd expect it to be new each time, as OS should allocate new address each run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation for `Object.hashCode()` can vary between JVMs as long as it obeys the contract, which doesn't require the numbers to be different between runs.  For HotSpot there is even an option (-XX:hashCode) to change the implementation.

HotSpot's default is to use a random number generator, so if you are using that (with no -XX:hashCode option) then it seems it uses the same seed on each run, resulting in the same sequence of hash codes.  There's nothing wrong with that.

lmm's answer is not correct unless maybe if you are using HotSpot with -XX:hashCode=4 or another JVM that uses this technique by default.  But I'm not at all certain about that (you can try yourself by using HotSpot with -XX:hashCode=4 and see if you get another value which also stays the same between runs).

Check out the code for the different options: 
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp#l555

There is a comment in there about making the "else" branch the default, which is the [Xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) pattern, which is indeed a pseudo-random number generator which will always provide the same sequence.
The answer from "apangin" on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111131/whats-the-default-hash-value-of-an-object-on-64-bit-jvm) says that indeed this has become the default since JDK8 which explains the change from JDK7 you described in your comment.

I can confirm that this is correct, look at the JDK8 source:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/runtime/globals.hpp#l1127

--> Default value is now 5, which corresponds to the "else" branch (Xorshift).

Comment: This is getting even more interesting than I anticipated :) I'm pretty sure you are right for JVM7, but I have doubts that hashCode=0 is default implementation for JVM8. I'm trying to find any tips, but for now no luck. Probably need to find a place where it is set in the source. The thing is that I receive different numbers each run when running JVM7, but for JVM8 I start receiving the same. It could be that JVM8 started using the same seed, and JVM7 didn't, but why? This seems awkward to change. At least I"m pretty sure that JVM8 has changed something compared to JVM7

Comment: @Archeg did a little bit more research, seems my answer was correct (random generator that results in the same sequence each time).  I added some more info.

Answer (score 2):

Some experiment:

```
scala> class A extends AnyRef
defined class A

scala> val a1= new A
a1: A = A@5f6b1f19

scala> val a2 = new A
a2: A = A@d60aa4

scala> a1.hashCode
res19: Int = 1600855833

scala> a2.hashCode
res20: Int = 14027428

scala> val a3 = new AnyRef
a3: Object = java.lang.Object@16c3388e

scala> a3.hashCode
res21: Int = 381892750
```

So, it's obvious AnyRef hash code is equal to address of object. If we have equal hashes it's mean object address is the same on every rerun. And that is true for me with two repls.
[image: And that is true for me with two repls.]

API tells about AnyRef hashCode method:

> The hashCode method for reference types. See hashCode in scala.Any.

And about Any method:

> Calculate a hash code value for the object. 
>   The default hashing algorithm is platform dependent.

I guess that platform determines location of object and therefore value of hashCode.

Comment: This is actually quite strange. Especially that you have the same hash with two REPLs. Does this mean these refs point to the same object in memory ? Or each REPL opens it's own JVM instance, and they just have the same offset?

Comment: Latter option. Each repl runs in own VM.

Answer (score 0):

Any new process gets its own virtual address space from the OS. So while the process might exist at a different physical address each time the program runs, it will be mapped to the same virtual address each time. (ASLR exists, but I understand the JVM doesn't participate in it). You can see this with e.g. a small C program with a string constant in (you might have to deliberately disable ASLR for that program) - if you take a pointer to the string constant and print that pointer as an integer, it will be the same value every time.

Comment: Who says his JVM is using the memory address for hash code generation?

Answer (score -2):

`hashCode()` is not a random number. It is a digested result from analyzing some part of an object. Objects with the same values will, more than likely, have the same hash code. This is true for your case, since the "value" of an `AnyRef` with no fields is essentially empty.

Comment: Not sure I can agree with you. If I instantiate two instances of type `AnyRef`, they will have two different hashcodes always. If I understood it correctly in case of `AnyRef`it should take hashcode of `new Object().getHashCode()` from java, which is the address of an object in memory. This is always different for two different instances, and probably should change in between runs. You are probably right for other types, but `AnyRef` does not have fields, so it should generate hashcode differently

Comment: I see that you are correct. My assumptions were wrong. For the sample code that you provided, though, the object would always be allocated at exactly the same place in the heap, since the JVM was fresh. Hence, the hashCode() would be the same. I assume (there I go again!) that you have a larger example that demonstrates the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: This is very interesting property of JVM. Anywhere I can read more about this?

Comment: Likely the source code. It's not a property though, since it is not a value that can be counted upon.