# System.identityHashCode() can the same hashCode be returned after an Object is GC'ed

Tags: java, jvm, hashcode

Assume `System.identityHashCode(object1)==123` and `object1` is garbage collected. Is it possible that a new created `object2` can have the same identity hash code as `object1` had before it was GC'ed ?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly possible.

Comment: It is even possible that two objects that exist at the same time have the same `identityHashCode`.

Comment: Note that the behaviour of `System.identityHashCode()` is the same as that of `Object.hashCode()` - it just ignores any `hashCode()` overrides in sub classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible that a new created object2 can have the same identity hash code as object1 got before it was GC'ed ?

Yes it is.

The identity hashcode *might* be *derived* from the address of the object when the method is first called for the object.  (Or it *might* be generated some other way.  The spec allows a lot of different mechanisms to be used.)

So, if the GC collects `object1`, and a new object `object2` is allocated at the same address as the original one, and the new one *may* have the same hashcode as the original.

Furthermore, if the GC **moves** `object1` after the hashcode has been generated, the new object (`object2`) at `object1`'s original.  Then, you could then end up with two *existing* objects having the same hashcode.

But neither of these things should be a problem.  Hashcodes are not not designed to be identifiers for objects.  (So don't try and use them as such.)

---

> My understanding of identity is that objects are unique inside a JVM at a given point in time.

The identity is unique.  The identity hashcodes are not.  As the `Object` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) says:

> *"As much as is reasonably practical, the `hashCode` method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects."*

That is nowhere near a guarantee of uniqueness.

And then:

> *"(This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the Java™ programming language.)"*

What it is referring to is the address of the object when `hashCode()` is first called.  The contract for the `hashCode()` method states that the hashcode value cannot change.  The identity hashcode is ... in effect ... remembered as part of the object so that the object can be moved by the GC.

And note that the latest javadocs have dropped all mention of how an identity hashcode is or might be generated.  This change happened in [Java 12](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()).

Comment: Is there any offical documentation about this? My understanding of _identity_ is that objects are unique inside a JVM at a given point in time. @Mark Rotteveel says in his comment, that the identiyHashCode cof 2 object can be the same at runtime, this is contrair to -> the identity hash code is the address the object was allocated on.

Comment: But the identity hash code is not the address the object was allocated on - the statement is "it is (typically) **derived** from from the address ...". See also the explanations at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111131/whats-the-default-hash-value-of-an-object-on-64-bit-jvm

Comment: *"this is contrair to -> the identity hash code is the address the object was allocated on"* - No it isn't.  (Even ignoring the "derived from" point.)  An object can be moved by the GC, and then a new object can be allocated at the first object's original address.  If that happens, both objects can end up with the same identity hashcode.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, by definition.

`identityHashCode` is an `int`. There are only 2<sup>32</sup> different integers in Java.
You can easily write a program that creates more than 2<sup>32</sup> objects.