# Is String intern is shared between run?

Tags: java

Everytime I run this program that I want to display the memory address, it always output same result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    String foo = "a";
    String foo2 = "a";
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(foo.hashCode()));
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(foo2.hashCode()));

    foo = "a";
    foo2 = "a";
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(foo));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(foo2));

    Thread.sleep(1000000);
}
```

The purpose of this is I am doing some performance test between Streams and Imperative style. So I would like to know if this value is cache, and determines if I should restart my pc or manually run garbage collection via JConsole / JvisualVm.

Comment: No. And `String` intern (and hash code) **do not** return a memory address.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch please correct my question, how can I display the memory address of string?

Comment: By using a language that allows you address memory. C++ or C maybe.

Comment: What do you want to display it for? And why is it a problem that it shows the same? i.e. what do you expect?

Comment: Please also explain the `.hashcode()` calls, what relevance do they have to the question?

Comment: @weston I would like to play or experiment, if String cache in String poll / intern when each run of main method. This is crucial for performance test, to determine if should I restart my pc or clear the garbage collection in each run, to uncache it from String poll / intern.

Comment: But it isn't cached. It's a new JVM. You can't 'clear the garbage collection in each run'. The test is pointless. Restarting your PC is pointless. It's all pointless.

Comment: Every time the JVM terminates, it's all gone. Consider it the ultimate garbage collection.

Comment: @ammoQ what do you mean by JVM terminates? do you mean after program runs?

Comment: @richersoon The JVM terminates when the program exits.

Answer (score -1):

`String foo2 = "a";`
may reuse an instance from the string constant pool if one is available. 
this can be proved by

```
System.out.println(foo==foo2);
```

`==` on two reference types is a reference identity comparison. Two objects that are equals are not necessarily`==`

it output `true` means *foo* and *foo2* reference the same memory.

**Related issues**
[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
[What is the difference between “text” and new String(“text”)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to find out the memory location of object, you can use **sun.misc.Unsafe**. But i wouldn't use this approach in real life. Just out of the curiosity :)

Here, the explanation of how you can do this: [How can I get the memory location of a object in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060215/how-can-i-get-the-memory-location-of-a-object-in-java)

BTW. Object.hashCode() returns the random number. By default it will use Lehmer random number generator.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question that was asked. By default, ['as much as is reasonably practical, the `hashCode` method defined by class `Object` does return distinct integers for distinct objects'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--). Nothing specified about Lehmer random number generators.

Comment: Actually the algorithm of generating identity hashCode can be altered by -XX:hashCode JVM option. There are the following options:

-XX:hashCode=0 - global Park-Miller RNG (Lehmer random number generator. default until Java 7);
-XX:hashCode=1 - function(obj_address, global_state);
-XX:hashCode=2 - constant 1. All objects will have the same hashCode. Just for testing.;
-XX:hashCode=3 - incremental counter.;
-XX:hashCode=4 - lower 32 bits of the object address in the Heap;
-XX:hashCode=5 - thread-local Marsaglia's Xor-shift RNG (default since Java 8);

Comment: Exactly, so 'by default' what it does isn't specified.

Comment: You can edit the answer and put the detail in there about random etc. Please link a reference, it's interesting.

Comment: OK, well that doesn't mention the options. I guess you got it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26049632/360211 or same place as that user did.

Comment: @weston Perhaps, you didn't read the article yet. Right after a chapter **The Actual Identity Hash Generation** you will find these options.

Comment: I saw it. No mention of the JVM flags at all on that page though.