# Why generated the same hashcode for Object when restart application?

Tags: java, hash, jvm, hashcode

I'm trying to figure out how the hash code is generated. I accidentally discovered one feature. As I understand in basic implementation hashCode generated with some randomized function. And I tried to generate hashCodes to see hashCode values. But I noticed that every time I start the test hash codes is the same:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(new Object().hashCode());
        }
    }
```

And I always see the same hash codes:

```
854507466
1316061703
490150701
1413246829
334203599
1372082959
1946403944
1131645570
209833425
532854629
```

Why they are the same every time I run the test?

Comment: The standard hashcode for objects is calculated in a JVM-specific way (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26049632/5646962). That means there is no guarantee either way: it can be completely deterministic (if running with `-XX:hashCode=2`) or it can be seemingly complete random (if running with `-XX:hashCode=0`). The default with Java 8 and later seems to be `-XX:hashCode=5`, which generates a pseudo-random sequence starting with the same value.

Comment: Thanks. I tested with this option. It works. But it is required to use  -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions because I got the error: VM option 'hashCode' is experimental and must be enabled via -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions

Answer (score 0):

Compare your hashCodes with those generated by:

```
System.identityHashCode(Object x)
```

My understanding is that this is the default implementation, and gets its number from the memory pointer location for that object, which would guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: x.hashCode() and System.identityHashCode(Object x) values identical for all -XX:hashCode values. The default -XX:hashCode value is 5, I verified experimentally. Regarding memory pointer location it is -XX:hashCode=4 - lower 32 bits of the object address in the Heap. See stackoverflow.com/a/26049632/5646962